# How to find a value inside a list that is inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to find a value inside a list that is inside a dictionary whitout using the key
and the purpose is so that i cant add the same name to the dictionary.

The dictionary looks something like this:

```
Dict={'1_number': ['1_name'], '2_number': ['2_name', '3_name']}
```

so i am trying to check if 3_name exists inside the dictionary.

Also trying to display 2_number by searching for it with 2_name, that is displaying the key by finding it with one of its values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually combine list comprehension to iterate over the values of a dictionary with `any` for short circuit evaluation to search an item to get the desired result

```
>>> any('3_name' in item for item in Dict.values())
True
```

alternatively, if you are interested to return all instances of dictionaries which have the concerned item, just ensure that the condition to check the item in its value is within the if statement and key value pair is returned as part of the filter List Comprehension

```
>>> [(k, v) for k, v in Dict.items() if '3_name' in v]
[('2_number', ['2_name', '3_name'])]
```

Finally, if you are sure there is one and only one item, or you would like to return the first hit, use a generator with a next

```
>>> next((k, v) for k, v in Dict.items() if '3_name' in v)
('2_number', ['2_name', '3_name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate of the values of a dictionary and check for the pressence of the wanted list value:

```
>>> def find_in_dict(d, name):
>>>    for k,vals in d.iteritems():
>>>        if name in vals:
>>>           return k
>>>    else:
>>>       return False

>>> find_in_dict(d,'3_name')
'2_number'
>>> find_in_dict(d,'4_name')
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to search the values of the dictionary, then return a `tuple` of `(key, value)` if you find the key corresponding to the value you are searching for.

```
d = {'1_number': ['1_name'], '2_number': ['2_name', '3_name']}
search = '3_name'

>>> [(key, value) for key, value in d.items() if search in value]
[('2_number', ['2_name', '3_name'])]
```